# Heroku deploy error Rails/webpacker ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "inline-react-svg"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpacker

I'm getting "Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "inline-react-svg" while trying to Heroku after adding `babel-plugin-inline-react-svg` to the package.json. I wasn't able to reproduce it locally, but I'm consistently getting it in Heroku.

Any ideas on what it could be?

**Error**

```
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
...
remote:        Webpacker is installed  
remote:        Using /tmp/build_15fd574408d6d2198a86094007ac9832/config/webpacker.yml file for setting up webpack paths
remote:        Compiling…
remote:        Compilation failed:
remote:        Hash: 7d0d7bb7df3a7fe42f08
remote:        Version: webpack 3.6.0
remote:        Time: 923ms
...
remote:
remote:        ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/orders.jsx
remote:        Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "inline-react-svg" specified in "/tmp/build_15fd574408d6d2198a86094007ac9832/.babelrc" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "/tmp/build_15fd574408d6d2198a86094007ac9832"
remote:            at /tmp/build_15fd574408d6d2198a86094007ac9832/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:180:17
remote:            at Array.map (<anonymous>)
remote:            at Function.normalisePlugins (/tmp/build_15fd574408d6d2198a86094007ac9832/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:158:20)
remote:            at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/tmp/build_15fd574408d6d2198a86094007ac9832/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:234:36)
remote:            at OptionManager.init (/tmp/build_15fd574408d6d2198a86094007ac9832/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
remote:            at File.initOptions (/tmp/build_15fd574408d6d2198a86094007ac9832/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65)
remote:            at new File (/tmp/build_15fd574408d6d2198a86094007ac9832/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24)
remote:            at Pipeline.transform (/tmp/build_15fd574408d6d2198a86094007ac9832/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)
remote:            at transpile (/tmp/build_15fd574408d6d2198a86094007ac9832/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:50:20)
remote:            at /tmp/build_15fd574408d6d2198a86094007ac9832/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/fs-cache.js:118:18
remote:            at ReadFileContext.callback (/tmp/build_15fd574408d6d2198a86094007ac9832/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/fs-cache.js:31:21)
```

**.babelrc**

```
  "plugins": [
    "inline-react-svg",
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    [
      "transform-class-properties",
      {
        "spec": true
      }
    ],
    [
      "transform-runtime",
      {
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ]
  ],
```

**package.json**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^22.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-inline-react-svg": "^0.5.4",
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to move `babel-plugin-inline-react-svg` to `dependencies` since Heroku installs without `devDependencies`.